# Chat edit box not visible

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, mobile-safari

When I try to post a message using the new chat on mobile, I can't see the edit box and I can't scroll down. I have to type on good luck.

> [image: Screen shot]

Please show the edit box.

---

I am on iOS 9.3.2 on an iPhone 6